# I am using spark 1.4 and trying to save as orcfile with compression snappy but it saves as zlib

Tags: apache-spark, orc

here is my code:

```
val df=hiveContext.write.format("orc").options("orc.compression","SNAPPY").save(
"xyz")
```

but file is saved as ZLIB.

Comment: But in all seriousness, your question is lacking substance. We can't help you if all you give us is "It's not working". What is the error? What happens exactly? What is the desired outcome that you wish to see?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the extra conf "spark.io.compression.codec=snappy" to spark-shell / spark-submit:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.io.compression.codec=snappy #rest of your command..
```

Also, for writing to ORC format (assuming you are in Spark >= 1.5) you can use:

```
myDf.orc("/some/path")
```

The "orc" method is exactly like doing '.format("orc").save("/some/path")'.