# saveAsHadoopFile - files extension

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, snappy

I'm using `saveAsHadoopFile` of `JavaPairRDD` to save RDD as avro file with snappy compression. Is it possible to force extension of output files to be `snappy`?

Comment: I can't say for sure but you should be able to do something of the sort : `pairRdd.saveAsHadoopFile("/tmp/", <keyClass>.class, <valueClass>.class, TextOutputFormat.class, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.class)`. You'll need to replace <keyClass> and <valueClass> with your pairRDD key and value types, and adapt the output to what you are looking to achieve. Any better ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464990/i-am-using-spark-1-4-and-trying-to-save-as-orcfile-with-compression-snappy-but-i

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to write avro files with SnappyCodec but they are saved with ".avro" extension. I need them to be ".snappy" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AvroOutputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/mapred/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroOutputFormat.java#L161) has hardcoded `.avro` extension and does not allow to change it.
I've uploaded a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1862) to the Avro JIRA with proper changes. 
If you have similar problem you have to (as for now) simply subclass `AvroOutputFormat` and use it in `saveAsHadoopFile` method. For example in Scala:

```
rdd.saveAsHadoopFile("output/path", 
    classOf[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord]], 
    classOf[NullWritable], 
    classOf[YourOutputFormatClassName[GenericRecord]])
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I could find a working example of an RDD being written as an Avro file using `saveAsHadoopFile`? My RDD gets written as text but not as Avro. :(

Comment: @Amber you have to define InputFormat, OutputFormat and wrap GenericRecord in AvroWrapper. You could check this Java code: https://github.com/allegro/camus-compressor/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/allegro/tech/hadoop/compressor/mode/unit/AvroUnitCompressor.java#L72

and

https://github.com/allegro/camus-compressor/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/allegro/tech/hadoop/compressor/compression/AbstractCompression.java#L37

Dont forget to call:
AvroJob.setOutputSchema(jobConf, schema);
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, inputPath);